# Visual Studio code - vscode - Pylint(E5142:imported-auth-user)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, django-users

Doing the following in models.py from a Django Project:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Pizza(models.Model):
    """A pizza that our clients can order."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return str(self.name)
```

I got the following pylint error:

> User model imported from django.contrib.auth.models
> Pylint(E5142:imported-auth-user)

Why is Pylint rising this error? Despite the fact that everything seems to be configured right. Virtual env, python interpreter, pylint-django...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it doing the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
from django.db import models

class Pizza(models.Model):
    """A pizza that our clients can order."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(auth_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return str(self.name)
```

Importing `django.contrib.auth.models` in the same way as Django does with its db models.

Comment: This make the problem undiscoverable by Pylint, but does not fix it. Use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()` instead.